$\log(x) / x$ limits at infinity, where $\log(x)$ has a higher power
How can you show the limit of $\frac{\log^{c}(x)}{x^{c-k}}$, as $x\to+\infty$, is $0$ when $k < c$? (this was the answer I got plugging into Wolfram Alpha).
I know that $x$ grows faster than $\log(x)$, but lets say $c$ is a huge number and $(c-k) = 1$. I would think that the numerator $\log(x)$ raised to a huge number would be larger in the limit than simply $x$ in the denominator.
I have tried applying L'Hospital's rule to make sense of this, but I can't seem to cover much ground. Is there something I should look at?

For $c\le 0$ it isn't an indeterminate form. For $c>0$ you can consider $\left(\frac{\log x}{x^{1-\frac kc}}\right)^c$ and just refer to $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$.

This question is similar to: Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln^{\delta}(x)}{x^{\varepsilon}}=0 $ for every $\delta\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon>0$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Possibly see it as $$  \underbrace{\frac{\ln^c x}{x^\alpha}}_{\rightarrow 0} \cdot \frac{1}{x^{c-k-\alpha}}  \text{,}$$ where the first fraction goes to zero for any $\alpha > 0$ and the second fraction goes to zero if $c-k-\alpha > 0$ (i.e., $k<c$ and $0 < \alpha < c-k$).
